# Regression estimation in Eviews

Tags: regression, estimation, non-linear-regression

I estimate the dependency of export,gdp and human capital. If choosing the linear method, I got this:

```
Dependent Variable: EXPORTS 
Method: Least Squares   
Date: 05/23/15 Time: 18:20  
Sample: 1960 2011   
Included observations: 52   

Variable    Coefficient Std. Error  t-Statistic Prob. 

C           2.63E+10    1.38E+10    1.911506    0.0618
HC          -1.36E+10   6.08E+09    -2.233089   0.0301
GDP          2903680.   192313.2    15.09870    0.0000

R-squared   0.967407    Mean dependent var  1.90E+10
Adjusted R-squared  0.966076    S.D. dependent var  2.22E+10
S.E. of regression  4.08E+09    Akaike info criterion   47.15324
Sum squared resid   8.16E+20    Schwarz criterion   47.26581
Log likelihood  -1222.984   Hannan-Quinn criter.    47.19640
F-statistic 727.1844    Durbin-Watson stat  0.745562
Prob(F-statistic)   0.000000
```

The sign of HC coefficient is negative, which is against the theory.I have tried logarithmic, exponential forms, but I still get negative results for HC.
I wonder what is the way to estimate it right.
Thank you in advance.

[here is my data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ooi2ni4sot3bfoe/mydata.wf1?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Durbin-Watson stat  0.745562
```

It means that there is auto correlation problem in your model.